# Excel copy contents from one sheet to another without VBA/Macro

Tags: excel

I've tried to use the search function but I can only find VBA related entries. I am looking for something without VBA. Maybe a simple formula?

OK I have a sheet with more than 8000 entries from Column A to L
In each column there's an entry like name, date, region etc.

Then I have other sheets with Region, let say Region 1, Region 2 etc.

I want to copy the entries from the main sheet belonging to Region 1 to the Sheet Region 1, the entries from Region 2 to Sheet Region 2.

So for testing I created the following Index/Match formula

```
=index(Sheet1!A:L, MATCH(Admin!$E$1,Sheet1!F:F,0))
```

Sheet1 A:L = Area to search for
Admin E1 = Value to look for
Sheet1 F:F = Where to find the value to look for in main sheet

But when I pull this formula down into the next row, it gives me the exact same entry again (like duplication) and it does not continue looking for the next item in the sheet.

What am I overseeing here? Am I using the right formula?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use `INDEX/MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` formulas. A simpler way to do it would be to use the `FILTER` function. Let's pretend the table with yellow headers is your main sheet. The table with blue headers is the sheet "Region 1".

[image: Filtre]

Formula :

```
=FILTER($A$1:$L$11,$G$1:$G$11=1)
```

`A1:A11` is the main table, `G1:G11` the cells containing the region values. We keep the records when `region=1`. So in each sheet "region", you'll have a `FILTER` formula in A2 (assuming you keep line 1 for the headers).

Comment: I marked your answer as the one that resolved my issue. But what if I want to apply multiple regions? Let say I want to have Region 1 + Region 2 in one filter? Does this work?

Comment: Then use `=FILTER($A$1:$L$11,($G$1:$G$11=1)+($G$1:$G$11=2))`. You put conditions between `()` and combine them with `+`. With words : in the table located between A1:L11, select in the column G (region) records which respect the following condition : =1 or =2.

Comment: OK i figured it out. I added additional "Regions" by adding + ($G$1:$G$11=2)

Comment: OK finally solved. For some reason your answer popped up when I replied. Anyways...thank you so much